# Insert current date in to destination folder structure

Tags: robocopy

Is it possible to insert todays date in Scandinavian format (yyyymmdd) in to the destination folder when using robocopy ie

```
robocopy "\\myserver\newlayout" "\\myserver\oldlayout 20120511" /MIR
```

I just need to support this while we transition our folder structures.

Cheers

Aha I've solved it by looking at other answers.

```
set "myDate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%"
robocopy "\\myserver\newlayout" "\\myserver\oldlayout %myDate%" /MIR
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it. It will be easier for others to find it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even easier, you could do it with the single line:

```
robocopy "\\myserver\newlayout" "\\myserver\oldlayout %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%" /MIR
```